# Unable to locate element with xPath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, findelement

I'm literally going crazy to find an element in a specific web page. It's an "Enter" button but I haven't been being able to locate it.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input"}
```

(Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)

I'm going to share with you the possible selectors by ChroPath Extension:

[image: ChroPathSelectors]

[image: ChroPathSelector(1)]

**HTML INSPECT CODE "ENTER" BUTTON:**

```
<input type="button" value="Entra" onclick="parent.location.href='site.site.site'">
```

**1°ATTEMPT - PYTHON CODE WITH REL XPATH:**

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[1]/input[1]')
```

**2°ATTEMPT - PYTHON CODE WITH ABS XPATH:**

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[1]/input[1]')
```

I have checked if there were any iframes, but I can't find them.
Please, help me.

Comment: Ok, I tried but it doesn't work. But I am going to explain you better. In the page there are 3 "Enter" button. They are equals. The only thing that changes is the different "html address". That's why I used that type of argument for the function.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @josifoski. It is better to use custom xpath than autogenerated by browser. So in your case try to use the following xpath:
`xpath = '//input[@type="button"][@value="Entra"]'`

It will be easier to understand and support.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

I was wrong when I told you that there weren't any iframes in the source code.

There are 2 ones!

So this is the right code to click the "Enter" button:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(0)
browser.switch_to.frame(1)
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('td:nth-child(2) input')
elem.click()
```

To figure out, I recorded my steps with Selenium Ide for Chrome Browser, then I exported the python source code and I saw 2 switch_to.frame functions; then I did 2 plus 2...

Like you can see, at the end, I used a css_selector argument based on the recorded source code that I had exported.

I hope it's clear and useful for other people.

Thank you so much for your help and sorry for the incomplete information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
xpath = '//input[@value="Entra"]'
```